# Manipulate MySql timestamp value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, timestamp

I'm working with a MySql database and a web application; I use Firebase Functions (Google Cloud Functions) to retrieve data from tables and send it to the web app. When the record's create_dt and update_dt fields make it to the web application, they're an object that doesn't have any accessible properties.

I'm trying to display the create and update date values in my application, but whenever I try to display one of the values, the web application displays `[object Object]`.  Looking at the object in the console, it looks like an empty object with nothing but prototype properties

[image: Chrome Console]

I've looked around here and other places on the Internet and found a bunch of articles that show how to manipulate a MySql Timestamp (as a time string) in JavaScript, but none that shows how to actually access the timestamp value.

My goal right now is just to display the time/date value in my app, but ultimately I want to get it as a JavaScript Date object so I can format the output the way I want in my app. Can someone please show me how to do this? I don't get why the timestamp shows up in the browser as an object with no accessible properties.

My function looks like this:

```
export const get = functions
  .runWith({
    vpcConnector: 'myapp-connector',
    vpcConnectorEgressSettings: 'PRIVATE_RANGES_ONLY'
  })
  .https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // Checking that the user is authenticated.
    if (!context.auth) {
      // Throwing an HttpsError so that the client gets the error details.
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(AUTHCODE, AUTHMSG);
    }
    const idx = data.idx;
    if (idx) {
      let cmd = `SELECT * FROM companies WHERE id=${idx}`;
      return sqlStuff.executeQuery(cmd)
        .then(result => {
          functions.logger.log('Query result', result);
          return { result: result };
        }).catch(err => {
          functions.logger.log('ERROR', err);
          return { err: err };
        });
    } else {
      functions.logger.log('Missing index');
      return { result: {} };
    }
  });
```

The query code looks like this:

```
export async function executeQuery(cmd: string) {

    const mySQLConfig = {
        connectionLimit: 10,
        host: functions.config().sql.prodhost,
        user: functions.config().sql.produser,
        password: functions.config().sql.prodpswd,
        database: functions.config().sql.proddatabase,
    }

    var pool: any;

    if (!pool) {
        pool = mysql.createPool(mySQLConfig);
    }
      
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
         pool.query(cmd, function (error, results) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            }
            resolve(results);
        });
    });
}
```

On the client, I'm using AngularFireFunctions since this is an Angular (Ionic) app.

```js
getCompany(idx: number) {
   const companyGet = this.fireFunc.httpsCallable('companyGet');
   companyGet({ idx }).subscribe(
      data => {
        if (data.result && data.result.length > 0) {
          this.company = Object.assign({}, data.result[0]);       
      } else {
         this.alertController.create({
            header: 'Company Lookup',
            message: `The specified company record (${idx}) does not exist`,
            buttons: ['OK']
         }).then(alert => {
            alert.present();
            this.router.navigate(['/companies']);
         });
        }
      },
      err => {
            this.alertController.create({
              header: 'Company Refresh',
              message: `The process reported the following error: ${err.message}`,
              buttons: ['OK']
            }).then(alert => alert.present());
          },
          () => {
            console.log('CompanyPage: Company request completed');
          }
        );
      });
  }
```

Comment: Hi, we need to see the relevant part of the code

Comment: I'm executing a `SELECT * FROM table_name;` via my function and processing the object returned. There's nothing special about the code on the server.

Comment: Actually, so looking at the code, is my issue with how I'm copying my results into my local array? hmmmm....

Comment: Looking at the result that comes back directly from the query, it's an object with no properties. Just like I showed in the previous screen shot (I'd add one here, but SO won't let me do anything but comment and edit my original post.

Comment: @messerbill, I added the code.

Comment: @messerbill I thought you wanted to help me?